# How to debug a blackberry widget?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I'm trying to debug a blackberry widget with eclipse but the solution described in this blackberry [pdf](http://docs.blackberry.com/de-de/developers/deliverables/15082/BlackBerry_Web_Plug-in_for_Eclipse-Development_Guide--920930-0329090845-001-2.0-US.pdf) does not work.

Has anybody debugged a widget for blackberry yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I've debugged a complex widget.

One thing I noticed is that to place breakpoints i had to use the default eclipse JavaScript editor. Using JSEclipse editor it didn't work.